# my if condition is not working php

Tags: php

I want to assign some value in some cases please help me out, my existing code is

```
while($local_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){
    $category = explode('->',$local_data['breadcrumbs']);
    echo $category[2]; echo "<br />";
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2])) =='outdoor'){
        $cat_ID = 5;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='furniture'){
        $cat_ID = 20;
    }

    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Bathroom'){
        $cat_ID = 6;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Furniture'){
        $cat_ID = 15;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Office'){
        $cat_ID = 62;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Contract'){
        $cat_ID = 81;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Decor'){
        $cat_ID = 90;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Construction'){
        $cat_ID = 108;
    }
    if(strtolower(trim($category[2]))=='Tech'){
        $cat_ID = 133;
    }

    echo $cat_ID; echo "<br />";
```

}
Now it is not coming inside the if condition

I have edited the code,

Comment: please print $category  and check that white space  is used or not so please  use trim.

Comment: trim($category[2])  and use strtolower($category[2])

Comment: I have used if(strtolower(trim($category[2])) =='outdoor'){ .. but still not working.. I am shocked that where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a lot of `if's` you are better of creating a 'map' of your categories inside an array. This way you'd only need one if to test if a category is found

```
<?php
      $categories = [
            'outdoor'         => 5,
            'furniture'       => 20,
            'bathroom'        => 6,
            'furniture'       => 15,
            'office'          => 62,
            'contract'        => 81,
            'decor'           => 90,
            'construction'    => 108,
            'tech'            => 133,
      ];

      while($local_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
          $category = explode('->',$local_data['breadcrumbs']);
          $category_id = isset($categories[trim(strtolower($category[2]))]) ? $categories[trim(strtolower($category[2]))] : null;
          echo 'Category ID = '. ($category_id ?: 'Not found');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put condition like below

```
if(strtolower(trim($category[2])) =='outdoor'){
    $cat_ID = 5;
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: I have used this, but I don't know why it is not working... :(

Comment: @DarkBee please check, I have added full code now, may be problem in next line ??

Comment: If you place capitals in the right half of your equation  and use `strtolower` in your left part, then it can never work...